# Android dialog box dismiss prevents listview activity from being populated

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app with 3 button on the main activity. One of those buttons is a reset button which downloads, parses and populates the sql database and essentially removes all the changes made by the user.
When the reset button is clicked, a alert dialog pops up to confirm the action. If the user says 'no' (i.e. doesn't want to reset the app) the dialog box closes and the main menu is visible again. Then when the user clicks the a button to see a listview populated with items from the database, this doesn't happen unless I restart the app. I don't understand why this happens and there aren't any errors in LogCat.

```
public void resetApp(View view) {
    //TODO progress dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertBuilder.setTitle("Confirm reset");
    alertBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want reset the app and lose all changes?");
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // execute download task again
            new DownloadTask().execute(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
    alert.show();

    CandidatesDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new CandidatesDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dbHelper.onReset(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase());
}
```

Comment: Ummmmm, post your activity code?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add it!

Comment: @Jam : AlertDialog is showing or not?

Comment: The alertdialog is showing.

Comment: If you have found the fix for your problem, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

need to make these lines execute when the user selects 'Yes':

```
CandidatesDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new CandidatesDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); 
dbHelper.onReset(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase());
```